# How do we add Bundling and Minification to a project that was upgraded from Visual Studio 2010 project

Tags: visual-studio-2013, bundling-and-minification

I upgraded a legacy website project developed using Visual Studio 2010 to a Web Application project in Visual Studio 2013. Now I want to add some MVC components to this application including Bundling and Minification. But the App_Start folder is missing. Is there any NuGet package I need to install that would create the App_Start folder and add the 'Bundling and Minification' feature?

For instance, this project was also missing the 'Content' folder, but when I installed the jQuery UI 1.10.4 package via NuGet package Manager, it created the Content folder and add jQuery UI css files to it.

Comment: You can create an App_Start folder yourself and add it to the project if that's all you need. I suspect that bundling/minification is more involved, though. This is one thing I don't like about big, heavy IDEs; they discourage you from knowing what's going on under the hood.

Comment: I would like to know a standard procedure that would automatically create App_Start folder and install and configure at least the initial features of bundling/minification from where I can add/remove the css/js files to the bundles if needed. I am assuming VS2013 would have some functionality to achieve this but have not found any yet.

Comment: @nam also, in addition to my answer, I'll add the caveat: there is nothing special about the App_Start folder. I think they just introduced it in MVC projects for organizational purposes. If you look at the "special" [Web Project Folders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex526337.aspx) it doesn't include App_Start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Step 1:** Install Bundling and Minification (via the GUI). `Tools > Library Package Manager > Manage NuGet Packages For Solution`. Search Online for "bundling" and the first result should be `Microsoft ASP.NET Web Optimization Framework`. Install that.

**Step 2:** Right-click your Web Project and Add New Folder and call it `App_Start`.

**Step 3:** Add a new class in `App_Start` called `BundleConfig.cs`. It could look like this:

```
using System.Web.Optimization;

public class BundleConfig
{
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include("~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));
    }
}
```

**Step 4:** Load on ApplicationStart in global.asax:

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
}
```

**Step 5:** Add to footer of MasterPage. I usually do like this:

```
        <%: System.Web.Optimization.Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery") %>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MyScripts" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </body>
</html>
```

That way, jQuery loads near the `</body>` tag and you can put all inline scripts in a `ContentPlaceHolder` that renders after your main script references.

Comment: You don't have to load in footer... but its better to do it like that. If this is a legacy project with a bunch of inline jQuery that would break if jQuery ref is in the footer, you can still do this and just move all that stuff into the new `ContentPlaceHolder`. Takes time yes, but in long run it's better. If you have problems with scripts in user controls, I show how to move them as well in [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19256630/1810243).