# Asset bundling in ASP.NET Web Forms using Global.asax?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, global-asax, bundling-and-minification

I'm trying to add bundling (a la MVC BundleConfig) to my ASP.NET WebForms Application. I was referencing [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/08/14/adding-bundling-and-minification-to-web-forms.aspx) as a guide, but I can't access my class/namespace or the System.Web.Namespace from my Global.asax file. How can I access my classes from Global.asax? Thanks.

Comment: Make sure you are putting your code in the code-behind file `Global.asax.cs`

Comment: Try these directions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21642509/how-do-we-add-bundling-and-minification-to-a-project-that-was-upgraded-from-visu/21653380#21653380